# an operand like left shift operand in python but works different

Tags: python-2.7

I want to know what do the python code below:

```
1<<128
```

which its answer is

```
340282366920938463463374607431768211456L
```

Is it left shift or different?

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations

Comment: This is a very lazy question..

Comment: i didn't know how to search about this question. i tried a lot but didn't find anything! i typed '<<' but it seems Google ignored it! sorry

Comment: @user3140519, well, it happens :) You could just google "Python operands" or "Python operators".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, seems to be a left shift. 2^128 is 3.4028236692093846346337460743177e+38.

Comment: @user3140519: Read the first two paragraphs here (the answer is in the second): http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex